# ¿Como puedo reformular un query que usa subconsultas?

Tags: sql, tsql

Deseo reformular un *query* de un procedimiento almacenado que usa una serie de *subquerys* desde un `from`.

```
PROCEDURE RPT_MOSTRAR_ESTUDIOS(p_ndat_id NUMBER, p_nusr_id NUMBER, c_cursor OUT refcursor) AS

BEGIN
    OPEN c_cursor
    FOR

    SELECT DISTINCT COD_NIVEL
        ,NIVEL
        ,ESTESTUDIO
        ,OPC_CARRERA
        ,CARRERA
        ,CARRERA2
        ,FCHINIEST
        ,FCHFINEST
        ,EST_PAIS
        ,CENTRO
        ,CENTRO2
    FROM (
        SELECT est.NEST_CODIGO
            ,est.CNIV_NIVEL_ESTUDIOS AS COD_NIVEL
            ,(
                SELECT va.CVAR_DESC
                FROM BTR_VARIOS va
                WHERE va.CVAR_ID = est.CNIV_NIVEL_ESTUDIOS
                ) AS NIVEL
            ,est.CEST_ESTUDIOS_ESTADO
            ,(
                SELECT var.CVAR_DESC
                FROM BTR_VARIOS var
                WHERE var.CVAR_ID = est.CEST_ESTUDIOS_ESTADO
                ) AS ESTESTUDIO
            ,est.CEST_CARRERA AS OPC_CARRERA
            ,(
                SELECT UPPER(car.cgrad_denom)
                FROM per_adm_grado car
                WHERE car.cgrad_codigo = est.CEST_CARRERA
                ) AS CARRERA
            ,est.DEST_FCH_INI AS FCHINIEST
            ,est.DEST_FCH_FIN AS FCHFINEST
            ,est.CCEN_CODIGO
            ,(
                SELECT cc.ccen_nombre
                FROM PERSONAL2.PER_CENTROS_ESTUDIOS cc
                WHERE CC.CCEN_CODIGO = EST.CCEN_CODIGO
                    AND CCEN_TIPO != 'O'
                    AND CCEN_TIPO != 'C'
                ) AS CENTRO
            ,est.CPAI_CODIGO AS EST_PAIS
            ,est.CDPT_CD_DPTO
            ,EST.CPRV_CODIGO
            ,EST.CEST_CARRERA_AUX AS CARRERA2
            ,EST.CEST_CENT_AUX AS CENTRO2
            ,EST.NEST_NHORAS
        FROM BTR_DAT_PER D
        INNER JOIN BTR_ESTUDIOS est ON est.NDAT_ID = D.NDAT_ID
            AND est.NDAT_ID = p_ndat_id
            AND EST.CEST_TIPO = 'E'
        WHERE D.NDAT_ID = p_ndat_id
            AND D.nusr_id = p_nusr_id
        ORDER BY est.CNIV_NIVEL_ESTUDIOS ASC
        )
    ORDER BY COD_NIVEL;
END;
```

El problema por el cual deseo reformular esta consulta es porque la siguiente subconsulta...

```
SELECT cc.ccen_nombre
FROM PERSONAL2.PER_CENTROS_ESTUDIOS cc  
WHERE CC.CCEN_CODIGO = EST.CCEN_CODIGO
AND CCEN_TIPO != 'O'
AND CCEN_TIPO != 'C'
) AS CENTRO
```

... me devuelve más de un valor y esto me ocasiona un error. Por ejemplo, me retorna 2 registros que tienen el mismo valor de `cc.ccen_nombre`, esto ocasiona un error, lo que deseo es reformular el *query* de tal forma que me permita retornar los valores y si es posible eliminar los *subquerys* .

Comment: Bienvenido/a a StackOverflow. Deseas que nosotros lo reformulemos por ti o deseas aprender cómo reformularlo tu mismo?
Antes de eso, ¿por qué razón quieres "reformularlo"? es decir, ¿qué problema tiene actualmente?

Comment: Gracias por la bienvenida , el problema que tengo es que una de esas subconsultas de devuelve mas de un valor , y pues ahi tengo un problema , necesito retornar mas de un valor.

Comment: Cuál es la sub-consulta que devuelve más de un valor, y qué resultado quieres que produzca?

Comment: es la subquery (
                    SELECT cc.ccen_nombre
                    FROM PERSONAL2.PER_CENTROS_ESTUDIOS cc
                    WHERE CC.CCEN_CODIGO = EST.CCEN_CODIGO
                        AND CCEN_TIPO != 'O'
                        AND CCEN_TIPO != 'C'
                    ) AS CENTRO

Comment: qué resultado quieres que produzca?

Comment: que me devuelva mas de 1 valor .

Comment: Entiendo que la subconsulta devuelve más de un valor, pero no me queda claro que significa "devolver más de un valor" en el contexto del query original. Por ejemplo, ¿Quieres que devuelva tantas filas como la sub-consulta con los mismos valores en todos los campos menos en cc.ccen_nombre? ¿u otra cosa?
Y también ¿qué debiera hacer tu query si la sub-consulta no devuelve ningún valor? a) devolver una fila con esa columna en null b) no devolver ninguna fila?

Comment: Ahora que está más clara la idea, te sugiero editar tu pregunta añadiendo la información que ha surgido en los comentarios para que quede claro cuál es tu problema y qué es lo que buscas.

Comment: Leí tu edición, pero sigue sin quedarme claro. Cuando la sub-consulta devuelve 2 registros con el mismo valor, qué debe suceder?? Hay casos donde devuelva más registros con valores diferentes o siempre devuelve registros con el mismo valor?

Comment: te pongo un ejemplo , la consulta en general me debe devolver el NIVEL , ESTADOESTUDIO , CARRERA , FECHAINICIO , FECHAFIN , CENTRODEESTUDIO , ahora ese subquery me debe devolver el centro de estudios siempre que CC.CCEN_CODIGO = EST.CODIGO y que CCEN_TIPO NO SEA NI O NI C , pero si he tenido 2 estudios , ejemplo grado bachiller y maestria en el mismo centro , esta subquery retorna 2 valores , lo que causa el error . Deseo poder mostrar esos 2 conjuntos de valores.

Comment: amigo, sé que no lo ves, pero tu definición sigue siendo ambigua, esos 2 conjuntos de valores podrían significar varias cosas, y no se puede escribir una consulta así. Te recomiendo incluir un ejemplo de los datos de entrada de cada tabla y un ejemplo de la salida que buscas. Te recomiendo leer https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te pongo el ejemplo con un campo. Esta subconsulta:

```
SELECT (
        SELECT va.CVAR_DESC
        FROM BTR_VARIOS va
        WHERE va.CVAR_ID = est.CNIV_NIVEL_ESTUDIOS
        ) AS NIVEL
FROM BTR_DAT_PER D
INNER JOIN BTR_ESTUDIOS est ON est.NDAT_ID = D.NDAT_ID
    AND est.NDAT_ID = p_ndat_id
    AND EST.CEST_TIPO = 'E'
WHERE D.NDAT_ID = p_ndat_id
    AND D.nusr_id = p_nusr_id
ORDER BY est.CNIV_NIVEL_ESTUDIOS ASC
```

La puedes convertir a esta:

```
SELECT va.CVAR_DESC AS NIVEL
FROM BTR_DAT_PER D
INNER JOIN BTR_ESTUDIOS est ON est.NDAT_ID = D.NDAT_ID
    AND est.NDAT_ID = p_ndat_id
    AND EST.CEST_TIPO = 'E'
INNER JOIN BTR_VARIOS vA ON va.CVAR_ID = est.CNIV_NIVEL_ESTUDIOS
WHERE D.NDAT_ID = p_ndat_id
    AND D.nusr_id = p_nusr_id
ORDER BY est.CNIV_NIVEL_ESTUDIOS ASC
```

Esto lo debes hacer en cada campo que desees cambiar la subconsulta por la unión entre tablas.

Comment: Gracias Flxtr , tu solución es precisa . Cambie cada una de las subconsultas y me da los resultados esperados. Ahora una duda , como puedo compactar todos esos selects en una sola consulta y mostrarla en mi Store Procedure

Comment: De nada @ASP.NEET para poder ayudarte con toda la consulta necesitaría entender el objetivo de la misma ya que en el ejemplo que te puse se soluciona para el campo NIVEL y para el campo ESTESTUDIO haces una subconsulta a la misma tabla pero con un identificador diferente. Pero, siguiendo la lógica puedes transformar una segunda subconsulta de esta forma:

Comment: Pongo la resuesta en otro comentario porque se excedí el número de caracteres:

SELECT 
  va.CVAR_DESC AS NIVEL
 ,var.CVAR_DESC AS ESTESTUDIO
FROM BTR_DAT_PER D
INNER JOIN BTR_ESTUDIOS est ON est.NDAT_ID = D.NDAT_ID
    AND est.NDAT_ID = p_ndat_id
    AND EST.CEST_TIPO = 'E'
INNER JOIN BTR_VARIOS vA ON va.CVAR_ID = est.CNIV_NIVEL_ESTUDIOS
--La siguiente línea te da la segunda subconsulta pero ahora en un INNER JOIN
INNER JOIN BTR_VARIOS var ON var.CVAR_ID = est.CEST_ESTUDIOS_ESTADO
WHERE D.NDAT_ID = p_ndat_id
    AND D.nusr_id = p_nusr_id
ORDER BY est.CNIV_NIVEL_ESTUDIOS ASC

Comment: Claro , como te mencionaba ya tranforme todas las subconsultas , en tu ejemplo dejaste muy clara y precisa la lógica , muchas gracias . Mi duda en este caso era que ya una vez tengo todas las subconsultas transformadas dentro del Store Procedure , como puedo mostrar todos los resultados de  esas nuevas consultas como una sola .

Comment: Ya no será necesario realizar alguna otra subconsulta para mostrar el resultado, tal cual así como está construida la consulta con los INNER JOIN la reemplazas por la que tenías en un inicio dentro del Stored Procedure, solo debes seleccionar los campos que desees traer en la consulta

Comment: aver estaria quedando asi ?`
        SELECT DISTINCT 
COD_NIVEL,NIVEL,ESTESTUDIO, OPC_CARRERA,CARRERA, CARRERA2,FCHINIEST,FCHFINEST,EST_PAIS,CENTRO, CENTRO2
FROM (SELECT  est.NEST_CODIGO,est.CNIV_NIVEL_ESTUDIOS as COD_NIVEL,
(SELECT va.CVAR_DESC AS NIVEL
FROM BTR_DAT_PER D
INNER JOIN BTR_ESTUDIOS est ON est.NDAT_ID = D.NDAT_ID
    AND est.NDAT_ID = p_ndat_id
    AND EST.CEST_TIPO = 'E'
INNER JOIN BTR_VARIOS va ON va.CVAR_ID = est.CNIV_NIVEL_ESTUDIOS
WHERE D.NDAT_ID = p_ndat_id
    AND D.nusr_id = p_nusr_id
ORDER BY est.CNIV_NIVEL_ESTUDIOS ASC ) AS NIVEL,`

Comment: porque me esta dando un error de un missing right parenthesis en la primera consulta :L

Comment: Entonces, es muy probable que la consulta creada esté bien, lo que pasa es que hay un paréntesis que hace falta. ¿Por qué no creas otra pregunta mostrando ese código y te ayudo a revisar tu Stored Procedure?

Comment: seguiré tu consejo , creare otra pregunta para mostrar por completo mi Stored Procedure aver que falla