# Error reformulando un Stored Procedure ¿Qué falla?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedure

Siguiendo el hilo de la [anterior pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/27437/21) reformulé mi Stored Procedure quitando los subqueries y reemplazándolos por `INNER JOIN`. Luego pasé a reformular mi `Stored Procedure`.

```
PROCEDURE RPT_MOSTRAR_ESTUDIOS(p_ndat_id NUMBER, p_nusr_id NUMBER, c_cursor OUT refcursor) AS

BEGIN
    OPEN c_cursor
    FOR

    SELECT DISTINCT COD_NIVEL
        ,NIVEL
        ,ESTESTUDIO
        ,OPC_CARRERA
        ,CARRERA
        ,CARRERA2
        ,FCHINIEST
        ,FCHFINEST
        ,EST_PAIS
        ,CENTRO
        ,CENTRO2
    FROM (
        SELECT est.NEST_CODIGO
            ,est.CNIV_NIVEL_ESTUDIOS AS COD_NIVEL
            ,(
                SELECT va.CVAR_DESC AS NIVEL
                FROM BTR_DAT_PER D
                INNER JOIN BTR_ESTUDIOS est ON est.NDAT_ID = D.NDAT_ID
                    AND est.NDAT_ID = p_ndat_id
                    AND EST.CEST_TIPO = 'E'
                INNER JOIN BTR_VARIOS va ON va.CVAR_ID = est.CNIV_NIVEL_ESTUDIOS
                WHERE D.NDAT_ID = p_ndat_id
                    AND D.nusr_id = p_nusr_id
                ORDER BY est.CNIV_NIVEL_ESTUDIOS ASC
                ) AS NIVEL
            ,est.CEST_ESTUDIOS_ESTADO
            ,(
                SELECT var.CVAR_DESC AS ESTESTUDIO
                FROM BTR_DAT_PER D
                INNER JOIN BTR_ESTUDIOS est ON est.NDAT_ID = D.NDAT_ID
                    AND est.NDAT_ID = p_ndat_id
                    AND EST.CEST_TIPO = 'E'
                INNER JOIN BTR_VARIOS var ON var.CVAR_ID = est.CEST_ESTUDIOS_ESTADO
                WHERE D.NDAT_ID = p_ndat_id
                    AND D.nusr_id = p_nusr_id
                ORDER BY est.CNIV_NIVEL_ESTUDIOS ASC
                ) AS ESTESTUDIO
            ,est.CEST_CARRERA AS OPC_CARRERA
            ,(
                SELECT UPPER(CA.cgrad_denom) AS CARRERA
                FROM BTR_DAT_PER D
                INNER JOIN BTR_ESTUDIOS est ON EST.NDAT_ID = D.NDAT_ID
                    AND EST.NDAT_ID = p_ndat_id
                    AND EST.CEST_TIPO = 'E'
                INNER JOIN per_adm_grado CA ON CA.cgrad_codigo = EST.CEST_CARRERA
                WHERE D.NDAT_ID = p_ndat_id
                    AND D.nusr_id = p_nusr_id
                ORDER BY EST.CNIV_NIVEL_ESTUDIOS ASC
                ) AS CARRERA
            ,est.DEST_FCH_INI AS FCHINIEST
            ,est.DEST_FCH_FIN AS FCHFINEST
            ,est.CCEN_CODIGO
            ,(
                SELECT cc.ccen_nombre AS CENTRO
                FROM BTR_DAT_PER D
                INNER JOIN BTR_ESTUDIOS est ON EST.NDAT_ID = D.NDAT_ID
                    AND est.NDAT_ID = p_ndat_id
                    AND EST.CEST_TIPO = 'E'
                INNER JOIN PERSONAL2.PER_CENTROS_ESTUDIOS cc ON CC.CCEN_CODIGO = EST.CCEN_CODIGO
                    AND CCEN_TIPO != 'O'
                WHERE D.NDAT_ID = p_ndat_id
                    AND D.nusr_id = p_nusr_id
                ORDER BY EST.CNIV_NIVEL_ESTUDIOS ASC
                ) AS CENTRO
            ,est.CPAI_CODIGO AS EST_PAIS
            ,est.CDPT_CD_DPTO
            ,EST.CPRV_CODIGO
            ,EST.CEST_CARRERA_AUX AS CARRERA2
            ,EST.CEST_CENT_AUX AS CENTRO2
            ,EST.NEST_NHORAS
        FROM BTR_DAT_PER D
        INNER JOIN BTR_ESTUDIOS est ON est.NDAT_ID = D.NDAT_ID
            AND est.NDAT_ID = p_ndat_id
            AND EST.CEST_TIPO = 'E'
        WHERE D.NDAT_ID = p_ndat_id
            AND D.nusr_id = p_nusr_id
        ORDER BY est.CNIV_NIVEL_ESTUDIOS ASC
        )
    ORDER BY COD_NIVEL;
END;
```

El problema es que me da un error

> missing right parenthesis

En la línea antes del primer `ORDER BY`

```
AND D.nusr_id = p_nusr_id
```

Probando tu consulta tengo errores también :S
[image: Select Invalido]

Comment: Si tu base de datos es Oracle, no es adecuado que pongas la etiqueta `tsql`, este término es exclusivo para bases de datos de Microsoft. Más información la puedes encontrar en este [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL) para revisar acerca de `tsql`

Comment: listo corregido . alguna idea de como puedo juntar las columnas de datos resultantes de cada una de las consultas ?

Comment: De acuerdo. Antes de pasar a lo técnico, veamos el objetivo de tu proceso, ¿Cuál es el objetivo del Stored Procedure? ¿Solo es regresar el resultado de la consulta?

Comment: si , es solo regresar el resultado de la consulta.

Comment: Bien, ahora nos damos cuenta que no requerimos el Cursor, entonces hay que quitarlo y solo mantener todo el SELECT. Ahora me doy cuenta que tienes la clausula ORDER BY en las subconsultas, ésto nos puede ocasionar un error, entonces también se debe quitar de todas las subconsultas. Haz esas modificaciones y veamos el resultado que te genera.

Comment: antes que nada , agradecerte @Flxtr por la ayuda brindada . Te comento , logre hallar una solución a mi requerimiento en base a los bloques select  que habia transformado anteriormente usando LEFT JOIN , ahora el codigo ha quedado mucho mas compacto y limpio a lo que pensaba hacer en un inicio .

Comment: ¿quedó corregido el problema?

Comment: Ya que haces referencia a una pregunta anterior, no es mala idea que publicaras un link a la misma, pues al leer esta pregunta sin saber cual era la anterior, no se entiende a lo que te refieres.

Answer (score 0):

¿Para qué requieres el uso de un Cursor? Me parece que el siguiente código soluciona tu problema:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE RPT_MOSTRAR_ESTUDIOS (p_ndat_id NUMBER, p_nusr_id NUMBER) AS

    SELECT DISTINCT COD_NIVEL
        ,NIVEL
        ,ESTESTUDIO
        ,OPC_CARRERA
        ,CARRERA
        ,CARRERA2
        ,FCHINIEST
        ,FCHFINEST
        ,EST_PAIS
        ,CENTRO
        ,CENTRO2
    FROM (
        SELECT est.NEST_CODIGO
            ,est.CNIV_NIVEL_ESTUDIOS AS COD_NIVEL
            ,(
                SELECT va.CVAR_DESC AS NIVEL
                FROM BTR_DAT_PER D
                INNER JOIN BTR_ESTUDIOS est ON est.NDAT_ID = D.NDAT_ID
                    AND est.NDAT_ID = p_ndat_id
                    AND EST.CEST_TIPO = 'E'
                INNER JOIN BTR_VARIOS va ON va.CVAR_ID = est.CNIV_NIVEL_ESTUDIOS
                WHERE D.NDAT_ID = p_ndat_id
                    AND D.nusr_id = p_nusr_id
                ORDER BY est.CNIV_NIVEL_ESTUDIOS ASC
                ) AS NIVEL
            ,est.CEST_ESTUDIOS_ESTADO
            ,(
                SELECT var.CVAR_DESC AS ESTESTUDIO
                FROM BTR_DAT_PER D
                INNER JOIN BTR_ESTUDIOS est ON est.NDAT_ID = D.NDAT_ID
                    AND est.NDAT_ID = p_ndat_id
                    AND EST.CEST_TIPO = 'E'
                INNER JOIN BTR_VARIOS var ON var.CVAR_ID = est.CEST_ESTUDIOS_ESTADO
                WHERE D.NDAT_ID = p_ndat_id
                    AND D.nusr_id = p_nusr_id
                ORDER BY est.CNIV_NIVEL_ESTUDIOS ASC
                ) AS ESTESTUDIO
            ,est.CEST_CARRERA AS OPC_CARRERA
            ,(
                SELECT UPPER(CA.cgrad_denom) AS CARRERA
                FROM BTR_DAT_PER D
                INNER JOIN BTR_ESTUDIOS est ON EST.NDAT_ID = D.NDAT_ID
                    AND EST.NDAT_ID = p_ndat_id
                    AND EST.CEST_TIPO = 'E'
                INNER JOIN per_adm_grado CA ON CA.cgrad_codigo = EST.CEST_CARRERA
                WHERE D.NDAT_ID = p_ndat_id
                    AND D.nusr_id = p_nusr_id
                ORDER BY EST.CNIV_NIVEL_ESTUDIOS ASC
                ) AS CARRERA
            ,est.DEST_FCH_INI AS FCHINIEST
            ,est.DEST_FCH_FIN AS FCHFINEST
            ,est.CCEN_CODIGO
            ,(
                SELECT cc.ccen_nombre AS CENTRO
                FROM BTR_DAT_PER D
                INNER JOIN BTR_ESTUDIOS est ON EST.NDAT_ID = D.NDAT_ID
                    AND est.NDAT_ID = p_ndat_id
                    AND EST.CEST_TIPO = 'E'
                INNER JOIN PERSONAL2.PER_CENTROS_ESTUDIOS cc ON CC.CCEN_CODIGO = EST.CCEN_CODIGO
                    AND CCEN_TIPO != 'O'
                WHERE D.NDAT_ID = p_ndat_id
                    AND D.nusr_id = p_nusr_id
                ORDER BY EST.CNIV_NIVEL_ESTUDIOS ASC
                ) AS CENTRO
            ,est.CPAI_CODIGO AS EST_PAIS
            ,est.CDPT_CD_DPTO
            ,EST.CPRV_CODIGO
            ,EST.CEST_CARRERA_AUX AS CARRERA2
            ,EST.CEST_CENT_AUX AS CENTRO2
            ,EST.NEST_NHORAS
        FROM BTR_DAT_PER D
        INNER JOIN BTR_ESTUDIOS est ON est.NDAT_ID = D.NDAT_ID
            AND est.NDAT_ID = p_ndat_id
            AND EST.CEST_TIPO = 'E'
        WHERE D.NDAT_ID = p_ndat_id
            AND D.nusr_id = p_nusr_id
        ORDER BY est.CNIV_NIVEL_ESTUDIOS ASC
        )
    ORDER BY COD_NIVEL;
GO
```

Comment: Edite el post , me da problemas esta consulta también :S

Comment: ¿Qué manejador y qué versión de base de datos estás utilizando?

Comment: La bd es Oracle Version 10.2.0.2.0 y el manejador es TOAD for Oracle